# Applying CSS to random div which get selected after splitting of main div taken after clicking evrytime

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have one fine square box as a "div",On which after clicking gets splitted into n X n form every-time, with a random background color evrytime...Now the problem what I am facing is that after splitting of div i want to apply again some CSS to the random "div" inside it after clicking...Currently  in my code it is applicable only in the first "div" inside it as u can see from my code,as i have taken "next" property intentionally just to explain my question more specifically over here...
I hope i made my question clear..
Thanks,a lot in advance..
My code is provided in below link ...

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8vz7Fs9vsK2MXUxeDlLR3hyVVU/view?usp=sharing

Comment: *"My code is provided in below link ..."* No, the code for your question should go **in your question**. Don't expect people to follow random links to help you, and external links rot.

Comment: To add to Crowder, if you're going to give a link, you might as well make a jsfiddle.

Comment: @T.j.Crowder-With all due respest..I really understand what exactly u mean by it..Only just for proper formation i provided my code as in link..Before tht i tried tht code ovr here..bt formation was not comming correct..That's it..I will be very much thankful to u if u evn try to solve my proble..

Comment: @sanjay: **Again:** The code goes *in* your question, not linked. When you were asking your question, there was this big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area, and a preview area underneath. There was an entire toolbar of formatting controls across the top. If you want an answer, use the "edit" link on the question and put the code in, removing the link to Google Drive.

Answer (score 1):

Since your div is dynamically inserted, you need the live method and bind a click event to it.

```
$('selecteor').live('click',function() { //code });
```

See an [example here](http://jsfiddle.net/twe53zuf/)

Comment: @Syahrul-This is exactly what i was looking for..Thanks a ton for giving me ur valuable time....

Answer (score 0):

If I am getting you  correctly then, you can get a random integer in range by this :

```
Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
```

and you can get the all the div's based on some class $('.some_div') and get some random div based on above code line. min and max can again be set according to the  size of the `$('.some_div')`. hope that helps